# Firebase init project with NPM on Mac

Tags: firebase, npm

I am trying to initialize firebase for existing projects using firebase cli with npm.

But when reaching to install dependencies with npm, I get the following error:

```
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /Users/apple/development/firebase_functions/lafoule/functions/node_modules/protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command /Users/apple/.cache/firebase/runtime/shell -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! /bin/sh: --: invalid option
npm ERR! Usage: /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
npm ERR!    /bin/sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
npm ERR! GNU long options:
npm ERR!    --debug
npm ERR!    --debugger
npm ERR!    --dump-po-strings
npm ERR!    --dump-strings
npm ERR!    --help
npm ERR!    --init-file
npm ERR!    --login
npm ERR!    --noediting
npm ERR!    --noprofile
npm ERR!    --norc
npm ERR!    --posix
npm ERR!    --protected
npm ERR!    --rcfile
npm ERR!    --restricted
npm ERR!    --verbose
npm ERR!    --version
npm ERR!    --wordexp
npm ERR! Shell options:
npm ERR!    -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option      (invocation only)
npm ERR!    -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2024-02-28T18_14_10_172Z-debug-0.log

NPM install failed, continuing with Firebase initialization...
```

Any idea how to fix this error?